# Count times user won where user is in team

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I have a list of teams with a list of players next to it

(Would it be better/easier if the players are in a single cell?)

```
+Team Name+--------+--------+
|  Team 1 |Player 1|Player 2|
|  Team 2 |Player 3|Player 4|
|  Team 3 |Player 1|Player 3|
|  Team 4 |Player 2|Player 4|
+---------+--------+--------+
```

Then I have a list of games with what team played against what team and who won

```
+------+------+------+--WON-+
|Game 1|Team 1|Team 2|Team 1|
|Game 2|Team 3|Team 4|Team 4|
+------+------+------+------+
```

I'd like count how many times a specific player has won and how many times he has played

```
+--------+#wins+#plays+
|Player 1|   1 |    2 |
|Player 2|   2 |    2 |
|Player 3|   0 |    2 |
|Player 4|   2 |    2 |
+--------+-----+------+
```

```
        List of teams   Specific player
                 v       v
```

Using `=COUNTIF(H2:U999; A2)` does not work if a team composition is reoccurring

I don't know if it's matters but it's a online google spreadsheet

Comment: In last screen shot you have list of Players who played and Wins and your Question is, "count how many times a specific player has won and how many times he has played" !!

Comment: Better Post the Link of Google Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want it like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ycIDrWH6wi2bkci__S14ROGkpqCq3kMX/view?usp=sharing

Hope this helps

Comment: While including a link to a demo file is helpful the solution should be described in the answer itself because the linked file could be lost.

Comment: It helps yes, but is there a way to not have 6 players next to the games tab? For example if you'd play a game with 6, 8 or 10 players that tab would be massive

Comment: Yes, just insert new team and player in **`TEAM`** table and add new game, and then copy the formula down at **`GAMES`** and **`PLAYER`** tables. Don't forget to check and modify the reference range for **`VLOOKUP`** and **`COUNTIF`** .

I just made some modification in the example table (in Google Drive) to show what I mean. Check it out.